# CSS nth child to select the 3rd element and then every 4th?

Tags: css

I'm trying to select the 3rd element, and then every 4.

So it would select 3, 7, 11, 15, 19, 23... etc.

```
.project:nth-child(3), .project:nth-child(7n+4) {
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

What is wrong with the current code? It's not working, the margin is still set to 40px on the right margin.

Comment: No need to combine so many selectors. You can simply use .project:nth-child(4n+3), check my answer :)

Comment: The answer accepted is not right since it's redundant :) You are using more selectors than you need to say the same thing!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Issue**

Your first selector is selecting the third element:

`.project:nth-child(3)`

However, your second selector is selecting every 7th element starting at the 4th:

`.project:nth-child(7n+4)`

**Solution**

You can combine your selectors to eliminate redundancy and modify your second selector to:

`nth-child(4n+3)`

so that your final CSS reads:

`.project:nth-child(4n+3) {
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
    }`

This will select every fourth element (4n) starting at the third element and also select the third element itself (+ 3).

**Example**

Here is an example snippet:

```css
p:nth-child(4n+3) {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>16</p>
<p>17</p>
<p>18</p>
<p>19</p>
<p>20</p>
<p>21</p>
<p>22</p>
<p>23</p>
<p>24</p>
<p>25</p>
<p>26</p>
<p>27</p>
<p>28</p>
<p>29</p>
<p>30</p>
<p>31</p>
<p>32</p>
<p>33</p>
<p>34</p>
<p>35</p>
<p>36</p>
<p>37</p>
<p>38</p>
<p>39</p>
<p>40</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.project:nth-child(4n+3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li class="project">1</li>
 <li class="project">2</li>
 <li class="project">3</li>
 <li class="project">4</li>
 <li class="project">5</li>
 <li class="project">6</li>
 <li class="project">7</li>
 <li class="project">8</li>
 <li class="project">9</li>
 <li class="project">10</li>
 <li class="project">11</li>
 <li class="project">12</li>
 <li class="project">13</li>
 <li class="project">14</li>
 <li class="project">15</li>
 <li class="project">16</li>
 <li class="project">17</li>
 <li class="project">18</li>
 <li class="project">19</li>
 <li class="project">20</li>
 <li class="project">21</li>
 <li class="project">22</li>
 <li class="project">23</li>
 <li class="project">24</li>
 <li class="project">25</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use nth-child by adding **nth-child(4n+3)** which allows you to pick :nth-child(3) and above (if it was just n), but since it's 4n it means pick the 3rd element and then every 4.

```
  .project:nth-child(4n+3) {
        margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
        background:red;
  }
```

**nth-child(4n+3)**

**4n** = Pick every 4 elements

**3** = Pick element number 3

Therefore combined it means pick every four elements starting from element 3.

I suggest you to check this link out for more explanation: http://nthmaster.com/

**DEMO:** http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/GgbXPw